# NGINX restrict admin area on wordpress but allow wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?

Tags: security, nginx, nginx-config, wordpress-admin

I have a few websites which use the following code to restrict the admin area. So far have not found a better solution than this.

```
##> COMMENT - WordPress Admin Area Passwords 
location ^~ /wp-admin/ { 
auth_basic "Restricted Access"; 
auth_basic_user_file /home/bea/panel/security/.htpasswd; 

location ~ \.php$ { 
include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf; 
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm-website123.com.sock; 
} 
}
```

We are using a plug-in that allows users to see and under construction page but provides a login to allow website owner to view their website while it is being built. Have a look at the image below.

As you can see below the user is prompted to fill in a password to access the website but also they are prompted to fill in the username and password to access the admin area. this pop-up only comes up when the user has put in a password to access the website and clicks on "Access the site".

[image: Example]

After contacting the plug-in creator, they suggested to exclude `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`?

Or is there a better practice to follow. I have noticed from time to time that some plug-ins require access to the admin area to function correctly.

I may have found a solution:

##> COMMENT - WordPress Admin Area Password, usally for LIVE sites

```
location /wp-admin {
        location ~ /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php$
        {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm-WEBSITE.tv.com.sock;
        }

        location ^~ /wp-admin/ {
        auth_basic "Restricted Access";
        auth_basic_user_file /home/user/panel/security/._htpasswd;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm-WEBSITE.tv.sock;
        }
}
```

**I just want somebody to validate the code above and check that it is secure? I'm still willing to offer a bounty to validate its level of security.**

[image]

Comment: I have found this potentially. https://jeffreyponsen.com/restricting-access-admin-panel/. Mainly 
    // Place directly after the restriction block
   `rewrite ^/wp-ajax$ /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php;`

I am still trying to work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around for many hours I have found a working solution but I am not quite sure if it is secure?

```
location /wp-admin {
        location ~ /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php$
        {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm-WEBSITE.tv.com.sock;
        }

        location ^~ /wp-admin/ {
        auth_basic "Restricted Access";
        auth_basic_user_file /home/user/panel/security/._htpasswd;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm-WEBSITE.tv.sock;
        }
}
```

But it is a working solution

Answer (score 0):

I think something like below should do the job for you

```
location ^~ /wp-admin/ {
   auth_basic "Restricted Access";
   auth_basic_user_file /home/bea/panel/security/.htpasswd;

   location ~ \.php$ {
      include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm-website123.com.sock;
   }
}

location = /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php {
   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm-website123.com.sock;
}
```

Comment: Hello. I gave it a go but unfortunately it good not work. Also when I logged into the backend and try to change some of the features on the plug-in specifically the password that uses the admin-ajax.php. It just came up with an error.

Comment: I think has to be a `location /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php {
    allow all;
}`

Comment: I do not get the double password. But I get an error message which says an error occurred! Please try again later. Which tells me it is not correctly communicating with admin-Ajax.php.

Comment: Try adding the allow all to the `location =` to block

Comment: Sorry, yes, I already have that. Still, no go.

Comment: Can you see what error you got from the backend or in server side logs?

Comment: This is the last log entry `2021/03/11 11:58:02 [crit] 21443#21443: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm-WEB123.COM.tv.com.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 132.123.123.123, server: WEB123.COM.tv, request: "POST /wp-ajax HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm-WEB123.COM.tv.com.sock:", host: "WEB123.COM.tv", referrer: "https://WEB123.COM.tv/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=maintenance_mode_options"
`

Comment: And also: `2021/03/11 11:56:02 [crit] 21443#21443: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm-WEB123.COM.com.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 132.123.123.123, server: WEB123.COM, request: "POST /wp-ajax HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm-WEB123.COM.com.sock:", host: "WEB123.COM", referrer: `

Comment: I have added the entire template code I use.